# Move file to other folder and send the folder URL on email attachment

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Batch file:

```batch
@echo off
set source=D:\teste
set target=D:\trab

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir %source%\*.* /A:-D /O:D /B') do move %source%\%%I %target% & echo %%I %source%\%%I & goto :continue
:continue

set p/ AttachmentFullName=%target%\<<fileName.txt>>

cscript.exe //NoLogo "D:\partilhas\correo.vbs"  %AttachmentFullName%

timeout 20
```

VBScript file:

```vb
Set objMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set objFlds = objConf.Fields

Dim attachmentFullName
attachmentFullName = WScript.Arguments.Named("%AttachmentFullName%")

objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'cdoSendUsingPort
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail.SMTP.com"
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "NAME"
'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "PWS"
'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'cdoBasic
objFlds.Update
objMail.Configuration = objConf
objMail.From = "EMAIL@EMAIL.com"
objMail.To = "EMAIL@EMAIL.com"
objMail.Subject = "Email Subject Text"
objMail.AddAttachment attachmentFullName
objMail.TextBody = "The message of the email..."
objMail.Send
Set objFlds = Nothing
Set objConf = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
```

What I want is to get the file from a folder oldest to newest one by one and send an email with each attached. As the file number to send the same mail number and move the same number of times. Someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't too clear about the problem you're having, but presumably it's your parameter passing.

The line

```vb
attachmentFullName = WScript.Arguments.Named("%AttachmentFullName%")
```

assigns the argument of a [*named parameter*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6y04sbb.aspx) `%AttachmentFullName%` to the variable `attachmentFullName`. However, for that to work you'd have to actually call the VBScript with a named parameter of that name. Named parameters in VBScript work like this:

```
cscript.exe script.vbs /param:value
```

meaning that in your case the call would have to look like this:

```
cscript.exe script.vbs /^%AttachmentFullName^%:value
```

to actually get a parameter name beginning and ending with a `%` character.

More likely you want to pass the value of the batch variable `%AttachmentFullName%` to the VBScript as an [*unnamed* argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah2hawwc.aspx). To do that change the statement

```vb
attachmentFullName = WScript.Arguments.Named("%AttachmentFullName%")
```

to this:

```vb
attachmentFullName = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)
```

and call the VBScript like this:

```
cscript.exe //NoLogo "D:\partilhas\correo.vbs" "%AttachmentFullName%"
```

Note the double quotes around the variable, so your scripts don't break when a path contains spaces.

As for getting that batch variable assigned with a value in the first place, currently you seem to echo the filename in your `for` loop and prompt the user to enter it manually.

```
set p/ AttachmentFullName=%target%\<<fileName.txt>>
```

For one thing, the above statement is incorrect and would throw an error. But even if it actually worked you should assign the path to your variable inside the loop instead of requiring user interaction:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir %source%\*.* /A:-D /O:D /B') do (
    move "%source%\%%~I" "%target%"
    set "AttachmentFullName=%target%\%%~I"
    goto :continue
)
```

**Edit:** To add all copied files you need to remove the `goto` from the loop and append to the variable (requires [delayed expansion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993)). Add double quotes around each path *inside* the loop, and don't put double quotes around the attachments variable when passing it to the VBScript:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir %source%\*.* /A:-D /O:D /B') do (
    move "%source%\%%~I" "%target%"
    set "Attachments=!Attachments! ^"%target%\%%~I^""
)

cscript.exe //NoLogo "D:\partilhas\correo.vbs" %Attachments%
```

Then have the VBScript iterate over the (unnamed) arguments and attach each of them to the mail:

```vb
For Each arg In WScript.Arguments.Unnamed
  objMail.AddAttachment arg
Next
```

Comment: It works but just sent one file to other folder and one email and i want sent all files to other folder and the same number of attachments on emails